# ESLint complains that 'HeadersInit' is not defined, when according to TypeScript, it clearly is

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to use the `HeadersInit` type in my react/typescript project.  My problem is that ESLint thinks the type is undefined:

[image]

But as you see, typescript clearly knows what `HeadersInit` is.  When I click into it, the typedef comes from the standard typescript library

[image]

Why is ESLint complaining about this, when TypeScript clearly knows what it is?

My eslintrc:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["react", "prettier", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.spec.tsx", "**/*.test.tsx"],
      "env": {
        "jest": true
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

Package versions:

```
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.10.3",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
```

Comment: i think you have to add `browser: true` to the `env` in eslint config

Comment: @mocha, tried your suggestion, no change 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the [core ESLint `no-undef` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-undef) is running on your code, but core ESLint rules don't generally know about TypeScript syntax or types. In order to lint TypeScript code you should have your config also `extend` from one of the [recommended `typescript-eslint` shareable configs](https://typescript-eslint.io/users/configs).

For example, adding `"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"` to the `extends` list should fix the issue.

See https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started for more information and a general guide to getting started linting TypeScript code. Since you're still on the legacy ESLint config format, https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started/legacy-eslint-setup is most applicable to what you're looking for.